# R shiny mySQL dashboard

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, dashboard

I'm new to R and Shiny and have a general question on the capabilities of the shiny dashboard before I embark on any development.

I posted this on the R studio community but did not get a response

I have a mySQL database with employee information from several clients. It was initially for me alone to use but I have been asked to share the database with some clients. Questions as follows.

Can R and Shiny access and tabulate, plot data in a dashboard from a mySQL database?
Is it possible to enter or edit data back into the database from a Shiny dashboard?
Since the database contains data from several clients is it possible to set up a login for a shiny dashboard, and restrict user access to the data?

If anyone knows that this sort of thing has been done can they point me in the right direction or an example so I can do more research?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The winner of the [RStudio table contest](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/12/23/winners-of-the-2020-rstudio-table-contest/) shows that it's [possible](https://niels-van-der-velden.shinyapps.io/employee_directory_crud_app/). However, up to now this is more a proof of concept than a productive Shiny feature.

Comment: Thanks for that. ill have a look.